# Restrict Autolayout constraint between some range

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

Is there a way that i can specify the constraints of `Autolayout` between some range. for example i want the `vertical spacing` between two elements to not more than 100 points and not less than 70 points.

Is there a way that i can specify such type of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sure can. Just create 2 constraints with different relations:

[image]